# javascript function not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I have the following simple javascript function to slide an object up and down.

When I first click it should slide down which it should do and alerts with true which it should do.  However on the second click I want it to slideup however it detects firstclick to be true again.  Any ideas

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var firstclick = true;


function slidedown(){

    if (firstclick = true){


        $( '#rerooftext' ).slideDown(500);  

        alert(firstclick);
        firstclick = false;
    }

    else {
        $('#rerooftext').slideUp(500);
        $firstclick = true;
    }
}





</script>
```

Comment: check your browsers error console you will get your error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firstclick = true` should be `firstclick === true`

Comment: also `$firstclick = true;` should be `firstclick = true;`

Comment: btw, you should checkout `slideToggle()` in `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

firstly delete the `$` sign before `firstclick` in the `else` statement

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
if (firstclick = true){
```

It should be:

```
if (firstclick == true){
```

You're setting firstclick to be true instead of testing if it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
function slidedown(){

    if (firstclick == true){


        $( '#rerooftext' ).slideDown(500);  

        alert(firstclick);
        firstclick = false;
    }

    else {
        $('#rerooftext').slideUp(500);
        firstclick = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `if (firstclick = true)` is wrong in  your code. This will return true always. Please change the statement to `if(firstclick)`